# how to get process.argv in npm scripts for nuxt3

Tags: npm, argv, nuxt3

is there any way to get process.argv 001 in the following npm script code

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev --theme=001",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
```